# MegaRAID create a new virtual drive, with one disk in the Offline/Online state

Tags: raid, megaraid

I have a MegaRAID 9361-8i controller with a RAID5 with 3 HDs.
We just replaced all the disks with new ones, and the setup tells that 2 of the disks are "Uncontrolled Good (UG)" state and the other is in "Offline" state.

When I ask to "Create Virtual Drive", only the 2 disks on UG state are available. How can I make turn the 3 disk from "Offline" state to "UG" state?

Ps: I see that I can turn the 2 disk from "Offline" to "Online" state; but doing so, it is still not available fro the "Create Virtual Drive"

Answer (score 0):

Solved by selecting "Clear all RAID configurations".
After this, the 3 HDs were available for "Create Virtual Drive".